# Can you set up an Azure VM to use the ARM architecture?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, arm

For work, I'm currently developing a simulator for a set of hardware systems that communicate with each other via ActiveMQ. I have them up and running in a very simplified form (primarily because our client is still being a bit squirrely on providing details on what exactly they want simulated). Because some of these systems run on restricted hardware, there is an interest in running the code in an [ARM architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) environment to determine whether the performance of the code will be impacted. I'm new to Azure, and find the listed variety of machines baffling, and unfortunately my searches just keep landing me on pages discussing how Microsoft plans on *running* Azure on the ARM architecture.

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-template); Use the ARM template.

Comment: @Ramhound: I found that too, but it looks like the ARM there is the Azure Resource Manager.

Comment: Why can't you use the Azure Resource Manager to deploy the Azure VM.  Ultimately you will need the appropriate license if you plan on running Windows on ARM.

Comment: @Ramhound: I may not be communicating properly. I need to run a VM that employs the reduced instruction set of the [ARM architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture).

Comment: You are communicating fine, in order to do that, you have to run an operating system. I must be really tired.  Cause I just realized Azure Resource Manager is ARM but not the ARM architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't when you asked this question, but you can now. Microsoft announced the preview availability of ARM64 Azure VMs [in April](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-arm64based-azure-vms-can-deliver-up-to-50-better-priceperformance/). They are running them on Ampere hardware